# How to get the mod of every number on a list in python

Tags: python

What's wrong with this code? (I'm trying to get the user to input 10 integers and then return the greatest odd number, if no odds then return a statement saying so)

```
numbers = raw_input('Enter 10 integers separated by comma ')
numbers = [numbers.split(',')]
odds = [x for x in numbers if x%2==1]

if not odds:
 print "no odd number was entered"
else:
 print max(odds)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that `numbers` is a list of `str` instances.  Try `numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers.split(',')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Remove the square brackets on this line:

   ```
   numbers = [numbers.split(',')]
   ```

   Otherwise, the list returned by [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will be placed inside another list.
2. Convert the list of strings returned by `str.split` into a list of integers.  This can be done with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

   ```
   numbers = map(int, numbers.split(','))
   ```

   Otherwise, the `%` in the next line will be interpreted as string formatting, which will raise an error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File ".\t.py", line 3, in <module>
       odds = [x for x in numbers if x%2==1]
   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
   ```

---

Below is a fixed version of your script:

```
numbers = raw_input('Enter 10 integers separated by comma ')
numbers = map(int, numbers.split(','))
odds = [x for x in numbers if x%2==1]

# The Python standard for indentation is 4 spaces
if not odds:
    print "no odd number was entered"
else:
    print max(odds)
```

Demo:

```
>>> numbers = raw_input('Enter 10 integers separated by comma ')
Enter 10 integers separated by comma 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
>>> numbers = map(int, numbers.split(','))
>>> odds = [x for x in numbers if x%2==1]
>>> if not odds:
...     print "no odd number was entered"
... else:
...     print max(odds)
...
9
>>>
```